How to implement Bloc state management for a map with filters and a searchable marker list
I am working on a Flutter application where I want to manage the state of a map using the Bloc pattern. The map has the following functionalities:
Markers Display:
    By default, the map shows a list of current markers.

Search Bar:
    The search bar displays suggestions based on the current markers.
    It allows selecting a marker. When a marker is selected, it is highlighted on the map.
    If a selected marker is deselected, the map returns to displaying all current markers.

Filter Functionality:
    Applying a filter fetches a new set of markers and updates the map.
    The search bar then updates to show suggestions from the filtered markers.
    If the filter is cleared, the map and search bar return to displaying the current markers.

How should I structure the states and events in the Bloc for these functionalities?
How do I handle scenarios where filters or marker selections/deselections need to reset the map state appropriately?
I want the map and search bar to work seamlessly together, where:
Search: Selecting/deselecting a marker dynamically updates the map.
Filtering markers updates both the map and search bar.
Clearing filters or deselecting markers restores the default state.

Any guidance, examples, or suggestions on implementing this using Bloc would be greatly appreciated!
